# How to create a query to extract a value from my table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an oracle table and i want to extract a value from column ,this my table

```
id|document_number|container_id|state|
--|---------------|------------|-----|
1 |CC330589       |356         | 40  |
--------------------------------------
1 |CC330589       |null        | 99  |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to create a query that extract the container_id (value `356` ) whhere the document_number is `'CC330589'` and the state is `99`.

In my case I want the value `356` (not the `null` value).

Any idea how I can create the query ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no row that fulfills your requirements. The only row with state 99 has a null container_id.

Comment: Yes but the two rows have the same document_number value

Comment: Add some more sample table data, e.g. another docid with a 40 a row and a non-null value for 99.

Comment: Do you want to get container_id with same document_number as the record with state =99?

Comment: Yes I solve my problem based on response 1 thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from tablename A
inner join
(select document_number, min(container_id ) from tablename  group by document_number)B
on A.document_number=B.document_number
where A.document_number='CC330589' and state=99
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use fid all not-null values for the given document and use `EXISTS` to ensure that state 99 exists for the given document:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE document_number = 'CC330589'
AND container_id IS NOT NULL
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE document_number = t.document_number
    AND state = 99
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the result set you specify from the sample data. Whether it's the correct solution depends on your business rules which you have not specified:

```
select document_number
       , max(container_id) as container_id
       , max(state) as state
from your_table
group by document_number
```

Here is another solution

```
select t1.document_number
       , coalesce(t1.container_id, t2.container_id) as container_id
       , t1.state as state
from your_table t1
     join your_table t2
       on t1.document_number = t2.document_number
where t1.state = 99
and  t1.document_number = 'CC330589'
and t2.state != 99
```

Again, this will produce the specified result from the sample data but may be incorrect against your real data set.